# Why wasn't the Bible enough for the founding fathers of America?

Tags: bible, history, christian-living, united-states

In light of the 4th of July in America, the founding fathers created new and brilliant ideas and concepts by which the "new world" would and still live by.

**It is almost as if they created a new Bible by which man (in America) will live by.**

Why wasn't the Bible enough to live by and how does the Bible support the American constitution and ideas on our way of life?

Thank You.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the community has weakly decided to make "christian culture" off-topic, which includes heavily political questions like this one. Reference: [How should we handle questions about Christian culture?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1841)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why wasn't the Bible enough to live by? The answer should be obvious if you consider how most of the colonists (or their ancestors) got to America in the first place: a significant percentage of the original colonists were religious refugees, fleeing persecution from people who believed that the Bible was enough to live by, but *had their own opinions of what the rules the Bible gave meant.*  And when you're trying to build a stable society composed of multiple distinct sub-groups with backgrounds like that, each of whom still have their own distinct ideas about what the Bible means, saying "just look at the Bible" just isn't going to cut it.

And it's not like things got any better in that regard after the establishment of the USA.  If we look forward another 40-50 years, we have a record of more of the same, even to the point of direct competition and bitterness between Christians who were nominally brothers in the faith.  [From the account of Joseph Smith](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1?lang=eng), regarding the time before the experiences that shaped him into a religious leader:

> Some time in the second year after our removal to Manchester, [*ie.
>   the late 1810s*] there was in the place where we lived an unusual
>   excitement on the subject of religion. It commenced with the
>   Methodists, but soon became general among all the sects in that region
>   of country. Indeed, the whole district of country seemed affected by
>   it, and great multitudes united themselves to the different religious
>   parties, which created no small stir and division amongst the people,
>   some crying, “Lo, here!” and others, “Lo, there!” Some were contending
>   for the Methodist faith, some for the Presbyterian, and some for the
>   Baptist.
>
> For, notwithstanding the great love which the converts to these
>   different faiths expressed at the time of their conversion, and the
>   great zeal manifested by the respective clergy, who were active in
>   getting up and promoting this extraordinary scene of religious
>   feeling, in order to have everybody converted, as they were pleased to
>   call it, let them join what sect they pleased; yet when the converts
>   began to file off, some to one party and some to another, it was seen
>   that the seemingly good feelings of both the priests and the converts
>   were more pretended than real; for a scene of great confusion and bad
>   feeling ensued—priest contending against priest, and convert against
>   convert; so that all their good feelings one for another, if they ever
>   had any, were entirely lost in a strife of words and a contest about
>   opinions.
>
> ...
>
> My mind at times was greatly excited, the cry and tumult were so great
>   and incessant. The Presbyterians were most decided against the
>   Baptists and Methodists, and used all the powers of both reason and
>   sophistry to prove their errors, or, at least, to make the people
>   think they were in error. On the other hand, the Baptists and
>   Methodists in their turn were equally zealous in endeavoring to
>   establish their own tenets and disprove all others.
>
> ...
>
> [I knew] that if any person needed wisdom from God, I did; for how to
>   act I did not know, and unless I could get more wisdom than I then
>   had, I would never know; for **the teachers of religion of the
>   different sects understood the same passages of scripture so
>   differently as to destroy all confidence in settling the question by
>   an appeal to the Bible.**

And this is just talking about a bunch of Protestants. Imagine the confusion if Catholics were thrown into the mix! (And there were and still are plenty of them in America.)  Then add in people of non-Christian faiths, and even atheists, and things just get messier...

Having pointed that out, it's still very interesting to look at the Constitution and at early American laws and legal concepts, and see how much of them were drawn from Biblical precepts.  A surprising percentage of them have clear roots in Old Testament civil law.  But in order to build a strong civilization around them, they still needed to be formally codified as law, originally drafted in the modern, common language, with a clear interpretation.

Comment: Exactly. The primary issue was the state and church being the same entity.

Answer (score 3):

Because the founders were not Christian.

The American Revolution took place during a period of history known as the Enlightenment, when Christianity was falling out of favor amongst the European aristocracy and the educated elites in the European colonies.  So the Declaration of Independence (and other early American legal documents) were written from the perspective of Deism, instead.

This was, perhaps, a preferable outcome, since New Testament Christianity is not especially helpful in administering a political state and was not intended for that purpose; *my kingdom is not of this world,* in the words of Jesus.

I've written a more detailed answer here.

[Does Christianity provide the right elements for democracy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/does-christianity-provide-the-right-elements-for-democracy/39579#39579)

Comment: Dr. Donald S. Lutz and Dr. Charles S. Hyneman made an extensive study to determine which books the Founders relied upon for the basic ideas that went into the formulation of the United States Constitution.. 

“It very quickly became apparent where the focus of interest was concentrated in the minds of the Founding Fathers. Of the thousands of citations quoted to support their ideas, 34% came from one source — the Bible. Most of these were from the book of Deuteronomy which is the Book of God’s Law.